# Filter array of dictionaries by NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

while implementing search functionality I need to filter array of dictionaries. I am using auto complete textfield method for search bar and am storing it into string. I can able to parse the array,But facing with below json

```
[{"CertProfID":"4","Name":"Dodge","Location":"loc4","City":"city4","State":"state4","Zip":"zip5","Website":"http:\/\/cnn.com","Phone":"phone4","Email":"email4"},
{"CertProfID":"5","Name":"cat","Location":"loc5","City":"city5","State":"State5","Zip":"zip5","Website":"web5","Phone":"phone5","Email":"email5"}]
```

Here I need to filter the dictionaries to make it finish

I tried with below code but its returning array with null values :(

```
 NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
  NSLog(@"substring %@",substring);
  NSMutableArray *arr2Filt= [arraylist valueForKey:@"Name"];
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF  contains[c] %@",substring];
  filteredarr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[arr2Filt filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Comment: SELF is not a propertiy/key in you dict. So the result is of course 0 hits. (Muhammad Waqas answer)

Answer (score 10):

This code will solve your problem it will return an array of dictionaries

```
NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name contains[c] %@",searchString];
NSArray *filteredArry=[[arrayOfDict filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] copy];
```

> arrayOfDict is your original array of dictionaries

**Swift 4.2 Version**:::

```
let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Name contains[c] %@",searchString)

let filteredArray = arrayOfDict.filter { namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }

print("names = \(filteredArray)")
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 3):

You could use blocks instead. They are much less hand-wavy about match conditions.

```
NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
NSLog(@"substring %@",substring);
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
  return [evaluatedObject[@"Name"] containsString:substring];
}];
filteredarr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[arraylist filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here one observation is that `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` is a method of `NSArray` and you are using `NSMutableArray` instead.

Change `NSMutableArray` with temporary `NSArray` object for predicate.

For example:

```
NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];

NSArray *tempArray = [arraylist valueForKey:@"Name"];

// If [arraylist valueForKey:@"Name"]; line returns NSMutableArray than use below line
// NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[arraylist valueForKey:@"Name"]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",substring];

filteredarr = [[tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: i already done this its returning array of elements but i need get array of dictionaries back @kampai

Comment: Which elements you got? You mean you want to sort on basis of dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I know there is many any answer,
In my case I have stored values As **JSON MODEL** object, This is code for, using **JSON MODEL**

```
 NSString *searchString = searchBar.text;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSDictionary *temp=[evaluatedObject toDictionary];
        return [temp[@"user"][@"firstName"] localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:searchString];
}];
    filteredContentList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[searchListValue filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    [tableViews reloadData];
```

**searchListValue** is a **NSMutableArray** which contains Array of json model objects.If anyone need help regarding this, just ping me

Swift version above 2.2

```
var customerNameDict = ["firstName":"karthi","LastName":"alagu","MiddleName":"prabhu"];
var clientNameDict = ["firstName":"Selva","LastName":"kumar","MiddleName":"m"];
var employeeNameDict = ["firstName":"karthi","LastName":"prabhu","MiddleName":"kp"];
var attributeValue = "ka";

var arrNames:Array = [customerNameDict,clientNameDict,employeeNameDict];

//var namePredicate =
//    NSPredicate(format: "firstName like %@",attributeValue);  
//uncomment above line to search particular word
let namePredicate =
    NSPredicate(format: "firstName contains[c] %@",attributeValue);
let filteredArray = arrNames.filter { namePredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };
print("names = ,\(filteredArray)");
```

More about this [refer here](http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/filtering-swift-array-dictionaries-object-property/)