# How to Search Core Data using Dictionary in IOS..?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, nsdictionary

i have some attributes in my core data entity like

1. name
2. age
3. address

but here address is one NSDictionay(contains city, state, zip etc). 
now i want to search the data in that entity.

this is the code i am using

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name CONTAINS[cd] $string) OR (age CONTAINS[cd] $string) OR (address.city CONTAINS[cd] $string) OR (address.state CONTAINS[cd] $string) OR (address.streetOne CONTAINS[cd] $string) OR (address.zip CONTAINS[cd] $string) OR (address.county CONTAINS[cd] $string)"];

but i am getting error because of NSDictionary elements. please tell me what is the exact search Query to Use when the Entity attributes contains Dictionary along with other attributes..?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087465/filter-array-of-dictionaries-by-nsstring/28087917#28087917

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one - you can't do it. If you are storing a dictionary then the attribute is transformable and stored as binary data. You can't predicate into binary data.

Instead, you should create an Address entity and add a relationship to it. Now your predicate will work as it will traverse the relationship.

If you keep the dictionary you need to predicate for 'candidate' matches and then do another filter when the candidates have been loaded into memory (and the binary data unpacked).